# Canvas oversteps it's grid-row limits

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I put a canvas into a row of a grid-layout. The canvas doesn't except any maxhight limits of the canvas itself neither of the row-height limits. It just fills the entire user-controll. 
I have this layout inside a grid:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1"  MaxHeight="32">

     <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">...</StackPanel>

     <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition MaxHeight="12" Height="12" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Canvas Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="canvasBar_SizeChanged" Loaded="Canvas_Loaded">
             ...
         </Canvas>

         <Image Grid.Row="1">...</Image>
     </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

If I put another image instead of the canvas, it doesn't fill the entire user-control, but the canvas fills it. Am I missing any parameters here?

Edit:
SizeChanged and Loaded both trigger this function to draw rectangles:

```
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.Height = canvasBar.ActualHeight;
                    r.Width = Rectwidth;
                    r.RadiusX = 1;
                    r.RadiusY = 1;
                    r.Margin = new Thickness(RecOffset, 0, 0, 0);
                    RecOffset += RectWidth + RectLimiterWidth;
                    r.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));
                    r.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(LastBrcColor);
                    canvasBar.Children.Add(r);
```

Comment: What are you doing on `Loaded` and `SizeChanged`?

Comment: Loaded and SizeChanged: I redraw the canvas and put rectangles in it.

Comment: Set `<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" ...>`.

Comment: @Clemens, can you please add your comment as an answer so that marcel can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas does not clip the content of its child elements to its bounds by default. You need to set the [`ClipToBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) property to `true`:

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" ...>
    ...
</Canvas>
```